# Codenmae one how to make add a budge on top of an icon and place them in the toolbar

Tags: codenameone, toolbar

this is what i have triedout

```
notification = Command.create("", materialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_NOTIFICATIONS, 3, 0xffffff), evt -> {
       ////....
    });
    mainForm.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(notification);
```

[image: that's what I have managed to do so far]

I want to achieve this below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badging an arbitrary button is pretty easy: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/badging-arbitrary-components.html

```
Button chat = new Button("");
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(chat, FontImage.MATERIAL_CHAT, 7);

FloatingActionButton badge = FloatingActionButton.createBadge("33");
hi.add(badge.bindFabToContainer(chat, Component.RIGHT, Component.TOP));
```

The toolbar button is encapsulated though and shouldn't be badged.

To solve that just don't add commands to the title area. Instead create a completely custom title area by adding your own title label and a badged button styled any way you like. You can do that by using `setTitleComponent` instead of `setTitle` and avoiding the `add*Command` method for those buttons.

Comment: Very useful tip! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to place the icon in the toolbar

```
Button notifiations = new Button("");
    notifiations.setIcon(materialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_NOTIFICATIONS, 3, ColorUtil.WHITE));

    FloatingActionButton badge = FloatingActionButton.createBadge("2");
    badge.setUIID("Notification-Badge");
Container notiCnt = BoxLayout.encloseX(badge.bindFabToContainer(notifiations, Component.RIGHT, Component.TOP));

mainForm.getToolbar().add(BorderLayout.EAST, FlowLayout.encloseRightMiddle( notiCnt));
```

Comment: In this way you are reliying on an implementation detail of the Toolbar, that is the layout. Maybe the use of the add method, even if it works, should be avoided in this case?

Comment: which method can do better to avoid the above

Comment: Don't use `Toolbar.add`  You should use Toolbar.setTitleComponent and create a custom container representing the entire toolbar and commands